Netcode for Gameobjects - Client has very slow movements
I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer project using some tutorials on YouTube. For the movements I'm using the New Input System and CharacterController.Move, to rotate the player I'm using Cinemachine POV and defining a direction with gameobject and a Raycast. The idea is to make two players (1 Host and 1 Client) connect and interact with each other and the scenario.
The Host has a skin called "BURGUES" and the Client has another skin called "COMUNIST", I'm having difficulty in making a correct synchronization between the Host and the Client, the first problem is that the Host sees the two players (Host and Client) with the Burgos Skin, for the client it sees the two players with the Communist Skin.
The second problem is that the Client's animations are not being synchronized.
The third and most important problem, the client has very slow movements but the Host moves normally, looking for variables in Debug, apparently the Client is receiving a slower speed to move.
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float gravityValue = -9.81f;
    [SerializeField] private Animator playerAnimator;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject centerScreenTarget;
    [SerializeField] private WeaponController burguesWeapon, comunistWeapon;
    [SerializeField] private WeaponController currentWeapon;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject handPosition;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerInput playerInput;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite imagePlayer;
    [SerializeField] private HUDController hud;
    [SerializeField] private CharTypeEnum playerType;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerSkinController playerSkin;
    [SerializeField] private Transform head;

    private Vector3 playerVelocity;

    [SerializeField] private NetworkVariable<Vector3> networkPositionDirection = new NetworkVariable<Vector3>();
    [SerializeField] private NetworkVariable<Quaternion> networkRotationDirection = new NetworkVariable<Quaternion>();

    private int currentLife;
    private int totalLife = 100;
    private Transform cameraTransform;
    private int totaGamePlayed = 10;
    private int totaGoodGamePlayed = 3;
    private int totaBadGamePlayed = 7;
    private int quantLifes = 3;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    //Player ID
    private int playerID;
    private string currentControlScheme;
    private InputController inputManager;

    private float positionUpdateInterval = 0.1f;
    private float lastPositionUpdateTime;

    //Clinet Cache positions

    private Vector3 oldInputPosition;
    private Vector3 oldInputRotation;

    //This is called from the GameManager; when the game is being setup.

    private void Start()
    {
        inputManager = InputController.Instance;
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

        hud = FindAnyObjectByType(typeof(HUDController)) as HUDController;

        SetupPlayer(1);
        currentLife = totalLife;
        hud.SetupSlider(currentLife, totalLife, hud.GetLifeSlider());

        hud.SetupSlider(totaGoodGamePlayed, totaGamePlayed, hud.GetGoodKarmaSlider_1());
        hud.SetupSlider(totaBadGamePlayed, totaGamePlayed, hud.GetBadKarmaSlider_1());
        hud.SetupPlayerImage_Player_1(imagePlayer);

        //burguesWeapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        //comunistWeapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        if(IsClient && IsOwner)
            PlayerCameraFollow.Instance.FollowPlayer(head);

    }
    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        base.OnNetworkSpawn();
        // Verifica o papel e aplica a mesh apropriada
        if (IsServer)
        {
            // Se for o servidor, aplica a mesh do Host
            SetMeshForRoleServerRpc(CharTypeEnum.BURGUES);
        }
        else if (IsClient)
        {
            // Se for o cliente, aplica a mesh do Client
            SetMeshForRoleServerRpc(CharTypeEnum.COMUNIST);
        }
    }

        // Método ServerRpc para configurar a mesh do jogador
    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void SetMeshForRoleServerRpc(CharTypeEnum playerRole, ServerRpcParams rpcParams = default)
    {
        // Define a mesh para o jogador com base no papel
        SetMeshForRoleClientRpc(playerRole, rpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId);
    }

        // Método ClientRpc para aplicar a mesh para todos os clientes
    [ClientRpc]
    private void SetMeshForRoleClientRpc(CharTypeEnum playerRole, ulong clientId)
    {
        if (clientId == NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId)
        {
            // Se for o cliente local, aplica a mesh correta
            UpdatePlayerVisuals(playerRole);
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePlayerVisuals(CharTypeEnum charTypeEnum)
    {
            Transform currentTransform;
            switch(charTypeEnum)
            {
                case CharTypeEnum.NULL:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case CharTypeEnum.BURGUES:
                {
                    currentWeapon = burguesWeapon;
                    currentTransform = GameObject.FindWithTag("BurguesSpawn").transform;
                    transform.position = currentTransform.position;
                    break;
                }
                case CharTypeEnum.COMUNIST:
                {
                    currentWeapon = comunistWeapon;
                    currentTransform = GameObject.FindWithTag("ComunistSpawn").transform;
                    transform.position = currentTransform.position;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //currentWeapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            playerSkin.SetuPlayerSkin(playerType);
    }

    public void SetupPlayer(int newPlayerID)
    {
        playerID = newPlayerID;
        currentControlScheme = playerInput.currentControlScheme;
        hud.SetupBehaviour(playerID, playerInput);
    }
    private void UpdateServer()
    {
        //transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(IsClient)
        {
            HandleMovement();
        }
    }
    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;

        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        //Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        Vector2 movement = inputManager.GetPlayerMove();
        Vector3 move = cameraTransform.right * movement.x + cameraTransform.forward * movement.y;
        move.y = 0;

        controller.Move(move * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityForward", movement.y * playerSpeed * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
        playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityRight", movement.x * playerSpeed * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
        playerAnimator.SetBool("OnGround", groundedPlayer);

        // Aim direction
        Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Vector3.zero;
        Ray rayScreen = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
        if (Physics.Raycast(rayScreen, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 9999f))
        {
            mouseWorldPosition = hitInfo.point;
            centerScreenTarget.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
        }
        Vector3 aimDirection = (mouseWorldPosition - transform.position).normalized;
        aimDirection.y = 0;
        transform.forward = Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, aimDirection, 25 * Time.deltaTime);

        //handPosition.transform.LookAt(aimDirection);

        //transform.forward = Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, aimDirection, 25 * Time.deltaTime);
      
            
        // Handle jumping
        if (InputController.Instance.GetPlayerJump() && groundedPlayer)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravityValue);
        }

        if (inputManager.GetPlayerShot() && groundedPlayer)
        {
            //currentWeapon.Fire();
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Time.time - lastPositionUpdateTime >= positionUpdateInterval)
        {
            lastPositionUpdateTime = Time.time;
            // Send updated position and rotation
            UpdatePositionAndRotationServerRpc(transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
    [ServerRpc]
    public void UpdatePositionAndRotationServerRpc(Vector3 newPositionDirection, Quaternion newRotationDirection)
    {
        networkPositionDirection.Value = newPositionDirection;
        networkRotationDirection.Value = newRotationDirection;
        UpdatePositionAndRotationClientRpc(newPositionDirection, newRotationDirection);
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    public void UpdatePositionAndRotationClientRpc(Vector3 newPositionDirection, Quaternion newRotationDirection)
    {
        if(!IsOwner)
        {
            transform.position = newPositionDirection;
            transform.rotation = newRotationDirection;
        }
    }

    public void OnControlsChanged()
    {

        if(playerInput.currentControlScheme != currentControlScheme)
        {
            currentControlScheme = playerInput.currentControlScheme;

            //hud.UpdatePlayerVisuals();
            //RemoveAllBindingOverrides();
        }
    }

    public WeaponController GetWeapon()
    {
        return this.currentWeapon;
    }
    public int GetQuantLifes()
    {
        return this.quantLifes;
    }
}

I know this is not better or optimized code, but I'm trying to understand the base of netcode, to after make a good project.

if you have 100% based server controlled movement, then you willl feel slow, especially as you both move locally, then update the server which potentially moves you back a bit and dont include velocity
